# Strange behavior on Angular importing Modules

Tags: angular

I'm having a hard time to understand well how NgModel from Angular work, I will give an example of an issue that is happening to me.

I have 3 modules AppModule ( root module ), SharedModule, and AssignmentModule. Inside my AssignmentModule, I import some modal components that I made from ngx-bootstrap here is the code :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AssignmentManagerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TaskTemplateComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':template',
        component: TaskManagerComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AssignmentManagerComponent,
    TaskTemplateComponent,
    TaskManagerComponent,
    ModalTaskTemplateComponent,
    ModalTaskSectionComponent,
    ModalTaskComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    // GeneralModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule, AssignmentManagerComponent],
})
export class AssignmentsModule {}
```

Inside my SharedModule i have this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    ConfirmationPopoverModule.forRoot({
      confirmButtonType: 'danger',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    // MatMomentDateModule,
    // MomentDateAdapter,
    ConfirmationPopoverModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TextMaskModule,
    DragDropModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

I trying to put a simple mat-select from Material Angular inside my ngx-bootstrap modal. The problem that I'm facing I getting this error:

**No provider for InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy!**

I know this solution is just the import from this module: **MatSelectModule**, but I put there in SharedModule that is exported in my AssignmentModule. This error just stops if I put this module on my AppModule but is not an elegant solution. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you aren't importing MatSelectModule in your ShareModule, put this import there and it should be work fine

Comment: I put MatSelectModule  on my import and export from SharedModule and is not working =/

Comment: What error do you see when you import this module? Another thing that I forgot to mentioned it's not a good practice to create an module to export Angular Material Modules, it's better to import the modules that you need in an especific module

Comment: The error is like I'm not importing this module this "No provider for InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy!", but it works if I put on my AppModule, i want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is the mat module being used has a peer Dependency that is missing. Go to that ngmodule and install it there.  You should have seen a warning on install of matselectmodule. Try to uninstall and reinstall to see the dependency